# How to Include @ symbol in blade template page without it being processed as blade code in Laravel

Tags: php, html, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, laravel-blade

So my dilemna is this.

```
<p>Email: info@example.com</p>
```

Is being processed as blade code and won't re-size in my responsive bootstrap web page in my Laravel 4 framework.

Any ideas on how to get blade to ignore the @ symbol? It is probably a simple fix I just can't find it on the web.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following will avoid blade syntax:

```
<p>Email: info<?php echo urldecode('%40')?> example.com</p>


%40 is equivalent to @
```

Comment: Just because I am curious does this significantly slow down my web page upon load if there is a lot of content?

Comment: urldecode() is a small function. I don't think it will slow your application. However, I am not sure why @ is conflicting with your blade syntax. I am using "info@email.com" straight way without any problem.

Comment: using `urldecode()` doesn't look nice... I mean, if I am posting 100 emails, either I have to assign a variable or use the function in all 100 of them

Comment: ahh it was just due to the fact that the email I wanted to include was such a long string bootstrap couldn't break it down to resize. My text editor thought the @ sign was blade so it colored the text differently which made me assume that was why it wasn't re-sizing. Thanks for the help though i learned something new

Comment: Thanks a lot @Anam

Answer (score 9):

A really simple way would be this:

`someone{{'@'}}email.com`

`{{ $whatever }}` effectively gets transformed into `<?= e($whatever) ?>` (where `e()` does HTML escaping) so you can put a string there, and that will get output instead of a variable.

Answer (score 3):

There are also HTML helpers in Laravel, 
you can use the following to generate a mailto tag with an obfuscated email address:

```
# Generating obsufscated mailto tag
{{ HTML::mailto('myemail@mail.com','Some person'); }}

// Generates :
<a href="mailto:myemail@mail.com">Some person</a>
```

View more of these helpers at http://www.laravel-tricks.com/tricks/generating-html-using-html-methods